# Getting error messages when running the docker-compose up command on Linux mint

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Using the Linux terminal, I'm trying to run the command 'docker-compose up' but instead I get a lot of errors. The following is what is contained in my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
    volumes:
      - ./gitignore/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

and when I run the command on the terminal, these are the errors that I encounter:

```
~/Desktop/dockerPostgreSQL/docker-composer$ docker-compose up
Creating network "dockercomposer_default" with the default driver
Creating dockercomposer_adminer_1 ... 
Creating dockercomposer_postgres_1 ... 
Creating dockercomposer_adminer_1
Creating dockercomposer_adminer_1 ... error

ERROR: for dockercomposer_adminer_1  Cannot start service adminer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercomposer_adminer_1 (5d1ce2f6a1e6c4600e8482e87be3e60547955cdadbe64a2fb82facca14491291): Bind for 0.0.0.0:808Creating dockercomposer_postgres_1 ... error

ERROR: for dockercomposer_postgres_1  Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercomposer_postgres_1 (e339a5e928066244eed6f119cec4bb9863376264b58e38242034f20da72c7422): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for adminer  Cannot start service adminer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercomposer_adminer_1 (5d1ce2f6a1e6c4600e8482e87be3e60547955cdadbe64a2fb82facca14491291): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8080 failed: port is already allocated

ERROR: for postgres  Cannot start service postgres: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dockercomposer_postgres_1 (e339a5e928066244eed6f119cec4bb9863376264b58e38242034f20da72c7422): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Could anyone please assist me with this in as to what I could be doing wrong an what I can do to fix these errors?

Comment: `listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use`. Someone is already listening to port 5432 on your host machine. The same applies to port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

A service already use 8080 port.

You have to choose an other one in your docker-compose file (8081 for example) :

```
ports:
  - 8081:8080
```